# Blazor AspNetCore WebApi Return Error to Client

Tags: asp.net-core, error-handling, asp.net-core-webapi, blazor

My Api Controller:

```
[Route("api/warehouse")]
[ApiController]
public class WarehouseController : ControllerBase
{
    [Route("addwidget")]
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<Widget> AddWidget(AddWidgetRequest request)
    {
        try
        {
            // use underlying service to add a widget to the database
            Widget widget = await WarehouseService.AddWidget(request.Widget);
            // Return the widget, including Id and other stuff that service may have enriched
            return widget;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            // Return BadRequest with custom error message
            // Something like:
            // Return BadRequest(e.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

My Blazor Client

```
public class ClientAPI
{
    private readonly HttpClient Http;
    public ClientAPI(HttpClient http)
    {
        Http = http;
    }

    public async Task<Widget> AddWidget(AddWidgetRequest request)
    {
         HttpResponseMessage res = await Http.PostAsJsonAsync("api/warehouse/addwidget, request);
         if (res.IsSuccessStatusCode)
         {
             return await res.Content.ReadFromJsonAsync<Widget>();
         }
         else
         {
             // We have an error AND I want to see the error message
             // not just the response code
         }
    }
}
```

My blazor component then calls:

```
ClientAPI.AddWidget(request);
```

How do I get the details of an exception encountered in the server during the WarehouseService.AddWidget call sent back to the client so that when IsSuccessStatusCode is false, I can display that error message?

In .Net Framework I seem to remember being able to use:

```
Request.CreateErrorResponse(StatusCode.BadRequest, ex.Message);
```

but with core that option has gone.

Comment: Try calling res.Content.ReadAsStringAsync()

Comment: That's helped!  What I was ideally after was a serialized Exception object in the client so I could output to the browser console and see the full stack trace.  I know that's no good for prod, but during dev would be super simple.  Instead I've now got a grip of the logging framework and asserted control over the debug window (which was spammed to hell with all sorts) so I can use that for the detailed error info now.  Cheers!

Comment: Next step is to learn Global Error handling to simplify the whole thing.  Got a decent link @ https://code-maze.com/global-error-handling-aspnetcore/.  Some reading for tomorrow!